# What is the shaded area that appears around the outside of objects in Creality Slicer?

Tags: slicing, creality

I'm using Creality Slicer, brims and other anti-warming or adhesion settings are all turned off. when I place an object on the bed a shaded area appears around it (See picture).

[image]

Is this simply the area in which you can't print anything else in sequential print mode due to the risk of the print head hitting it, or is there some other meaning?

Comment: At first I would’ve thought it was a skirt, but all your adhesion settings are off…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creality Slicer is a derivate of Cura. As such, all standard Cura things apply.

### Cura uses red surfaces to denote overhangs.

Your upper surface is denoted as an overhang, this indicates that your item has its surfaces at least partially "upside down". The model needs to be repaired, as such can result in the print solution being "That's to be a closed surface", ignoring the hole in the center. The problem isn't the slicer, it is the generation of the STL that messed up.

About inverted surfaces, see also: [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/7385/8884), [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19044/little-help-on-this-cura-slicing-or-model-error) and [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/11013/8884)

### Boxes around items come from sequential printing

The box around parts is also usually created when you try to print multiple items in sequence and relates to the dimensions of your printhead. It pretty much marks the exclusion zone where you are not allowed to place the next item. Check if you have turned `print order` from `all at once` to `in sequence` and adjust as needed.

Comment: I picked a random STL to create a screen shot. This one is supposed to be "upside down" so that it can be printed without supports, I just needed something to import so that I could make a screen shot. It's set to In sequence by default, so this is most likely the exclusion zone.

Comment: @AaarghZombies yep, I prefer "all at once" for all but TPU

Comment: If you do "sequence" you can take the first one off the bed and start using it before the last one has finished. It's a real time saver if you're printing multiple components that need sanding or priming.

Comment: It is, but you can not use that with items above a relatively small height - If I print larger projects, the time saving for printing small parts in sequence is nigh neglectible.

Comment: The above item was simply the last thing I printed. It was a convenient example.